# Can't ssh to myself through internet?

Tags: ssh, openssh, timeout

I'm trying to connect to myself through ssh. (For testing purpose). I'm on a Ubuntu laptop. I successfully launched a ssh serveur, and "ssh localhost" works fine. If I try "ssh ", it works too. (I got it from ifconfig)
But if I try with my public IP adress (got it on whatismyipadress.com), it doesn't work, I get a timeout after 2 minutes. (Note that "ping " works fine)

Any idea about why I get this ? I wouldn't be surprised if the problem came from my router (or is it a modem, or something like that ? I don't know), which would be working fine but have no idea about where to redirect ssh request (maybe on a computer from home which doesn't run ssh server ?)

Comment: Have you forwarded the ports to your computer?

Comment: @Findus23 : I'm sorry, I have no idea of what it means. I guess the answer is no.

Comment: First, is your laptop behind a NAT? If so, have forwarded the 22 ports from the router to your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Findus23 says, you have to forward a port (different from the 22, which is perhaps used as default port to connect to SSH router itself) from the router to your PC.

I make an example:

```
PC [192.168.1.10] <==> [192.168.1.1] Router [1.1.1.1] <==> Internet
```

As you can see, connecting through SSH to the address `1.1.1.1` results in connecting to the port 22 of your router on his public interface (faced to Internet).

If you want to *access a PC located behind the router* (so, in the private network of address space `192.168.1.0/24`) you have to enable **Port Forwarding**.
This is mandatory because your router must know which host it has to contact from the full address space of PCs connected to it. For example:

```
(PC1[192.168.1.2], PC2[192.168.1.3]) <==> Router
```

Router cannot know if it has to route to `PC1` or `PC2` when contacted to a specified port.
Enabling `Port Forwarding` you can say:

> All connections from Internet to port X of the router, must be routed to port Y of PCZ

So, in your case:

```
Router:<port> => PC1:22 (route connection from router port 4000 to port 22 of PC1)
ssh -p <port> user@<router-IP>
```

results in connecting, from Internet, to the specified local host.